# How can I overwrite a route in Blazor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I use a second assembly in my Blazor project. Works fine. But both assemblies have a page which is  responsible for "/" route. A common index page in the referenced common library and a customized index page in the starting razor app. How can I tell the starting App that "/" should be only served by the page located in its own assembly?

App Code of custom assembly:

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" AdditionalAssemblies="new[] { typeof(Common.Server.Program).Assembly } ">
```

I get the following error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   InvalidOperationException: The following routes are ambiguous:
>   '/' in 'Specific.Server.Pages.Index'
>   '/' in 'Common.Server.Pages.Index'

Which makes totally sense but how can I handle it?

Comment: I don't know of a way to do this in the standard Blazor routing - which is why I never put `@page` directives in a component library (any more) - a "page" is a concept of the particular application, not of a component library. You can create your own router - https://chrissainty.com/building-a-custom-router-for-blazor/ if that is something you would rather do.

Comment: `@page "/"`
`@page "/index" `
Something like It?

Comment: @MisterMagoo, thanx for pointing me in that direction.  This is the project's repository (in case the blog died): https://github.com/chrissainty/BuildingACustomRouterForBlazor